# Hiding a form without calling FormClosing method

Tags: c#, forms, hide, formclosing

I have two forms and I have linked it up so that when the second form is closed the first is closed too (using the FormClosing method).

The problem with this is that when I wish to hide the second form it automatically closes the first. Is there a way in which a form can be hidden without actually calling the FormClosing method?

The FormClosing method still seems to be called when "Visible = false" and "Hide()" are used.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2021708/945456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my program so that it is started as below:

```
        MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
        mainForm.Show();
        Application.Run();
```

Instead of:

```
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

In each of the forms I have added a FormClosing event which checks to see if the user has opted to close the application. If this is the case a prompt is shown to the user to ask for their confirmation:

```
    private void ImageSelect_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            if (DialogResult.No == MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wish to exit?", "Exit Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo))
                e.Cancel = true;
            else { Application.Exit(); }
        }
    }
```

The application now can be closed from any form in the application.

Answer (score 2):

call `Hide()` on the form or `Visible=false`, but onsider in this case the the form remains in memory and all allocated resources by that form remain in the memory.

If this is a problem for you, I would suggest to revise your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`form.Hide()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx).

This just conceals the form from the user without actually closing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.Hide();
```

or

```
this.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use WinForms forms the method *Hide()* should be the one which you are looking for.

Comment: when I use Hide() it still calls the FormClosing method.

Comment: Maybe you can use property FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) within _FormClosing_ method to decide hwat to do.