# How do you open an already disposed form in VB?

Tags: vb.net, forms, dispose

When I close Form2 it won’t open up again after.

I am using a button click to open up another form. Right now I just have:

```
Dim Form2 As New Form2

Private Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
   Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

Now whenever I close the form I cannot open it again.

Comment: Do you want to open a new instance of the form, or are you expecting it to still show whatever state it had when it was closed?

Comment: @David The same state it was in when closed.

Comment: @BaileyNygard You will need some way to save the state, and a method to reinstate it. Do you want the state to persist every time the program is run or just for the current run?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Just the current run

Comment: @BaileyNygard Instead of closing Form2, could you hide it? [Hide form instead of closing when close button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2021681/1115360) is in C#, but hopefully you'll be able to figure out how to do the same in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
Private MyForm2 As Form2
Private Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
       If MyForm2 Is Nothing OrElse MyForm2.IsDisposed Then
        MyForm2 = New Form2
    End If
    MyForm2.Show()
End Sub
```